# Is an Enchantment Creature card an Enchantment card?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

is it possible to return an enchantment creature card (like 
[Baleful Eidolon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373720)) with [Dawn to Dusk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=378378) from the graveyard? I'm not sure if an enchantment creature is a special type or just two types (enchantment and creature).

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Baleful Eidolon is an enchantment and a creature. Anything which targets or affects either of these permanent types can target or affect it.